# Bad name for [modern-ui] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

[modern-ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) was AFAIK never the official name from Microsoft. It was always either knows by the codename “Metro”, by the internally used name “Immersive” or by the moniker “Windows Store apps”

**Request:** Add [metro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/metro) and [immersive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/immersive) as synonyms for [modern-ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) (and possibly rename the tag itself).

Comment: `[metro-ui]` is already a synonym pointing to `[modern-ui]`.